# Typed methods in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How do I define the type of a class method in TypeScript? For a regular function, I would do

```
interface Listener { (foo: string, bar: any): void; }

// foo and bar will be typed according to the Listener interface
let listener: Listener = function(foo, bar) { };
```

Is it possible to declare a method with the Listener interface?

```
class Foo {

  // will warn about implicit 'any' types
  listener1(foo, bar) { }

  // I want to avoid this
  listener2(foo: string, bar: any): void { }
}
```

This would make it easier for me to override the method in subclasses, knowing that the methods need to conform to the Listener interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure that only objects are passed into for example a function that "have" a listener function you can also use an interface.

```
 interface IListener{
     listener(type: string, payload: any):void
 }

 function somethingElse( l:IListener ){
     l.listener( "hello", "heavy payload" );
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {
    //as method
    foo(): boolean {
        return true;
    }

    //as lambda method
    bar = (): boolean => {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But none of these set the interface of the method to `Listener`?

Comment: It was just an example of a generic typed method. Simply replace "boolean" with "Listener" to have it designated as returning that type. Unless I am misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I want to use an existing interface for the method.